# How can I prevent edit text being hidden by the Android keyboard?

Tags: android-layout

I have around 4-5 edit text on the screen, now when user types, some EditText are hidden behind the soft keyboard and user can not see what he is typing.

Please give ideas what can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I got the solution put a LinearLayout containing all TextViews and EditText in scroll view and then when user presses next view is scrolled and user will be able to see what he is typing.